# How to return a Map type in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

What is the way to make a function return a map typed output in scala?

The only way I could find was to use `.toMap` at the end

For example:

```
val names: List[String] = List("abc","abcd","abcde")
val out_map: Map[String,Int] = names.map(x=>x->x.length())
```

Results in

```
Found:    List[(String, Int)]
Required: Map[String, Int]
```

and works only if I do

```
val out_map: Map[String,Int] = names.map(x=>x->x.length()).toMap
```

Is this the 'the way` to return map type? Always have to convert the collections of tuples later on? Or, Am I missing some syntax to directly declare the anonymous function in a way such that `.toMap` is not necessary?

Comment: I already proposed to add a `mapTo` method to the collections library, it was not well received: https://github.com/scala/scala-library-next/issues/57

Answer (score 4):

`.map` method name refers to [mapping a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) - calling `x.map(f)` should be understood as "mapping each value from `x` using function `f` - where mapping means turning each value into argument of a function and getting function's value at this argument.

```
val c1: List[Int] = List(1,2,3) // something having .map method
val f: Int => String = _.toString
val c2: List[String] = c1.map(f) // each Int turned to String with f
```

This is close but not identical to `Map` which represent a data structure, often known as dictionary. In pure mathematics "mapping" and "map structure" might be similar/related, but their implementations in programming languages focus on different things and they shouldn't be confused. To convert standard library's collection of tuples into `Map`, you should call `.toMap`.

```
val c1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val c2: List[Int, String] = c1.map(i => (i -> "a" * i))
val c3: Map[Int, String] = c2.toMap
```

Names are similar since both deal with pairing values from domain (arguments) with values from codomain.

Difference is that `x.map(f)` *takes* a *total* function - an existing mapping for a whole domain that you have to provide - and use it for each value in `x`. Alternatively, you can think that it takes a subset of domain `f`'s and calculates for it a subset of a `f`'s image.

Meanwhile `Map` contains pairings only for some values, so you can treat *is* as a reification of a *partial* function, where you explicitly defined each pair.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is pretty standard way - convert list to tuples and use `toMap` on it:

```scala
val names: List[String] = List("abc", "abcd", "abcde")
val out_map: Map[String, Int] = names
  .distinct // I prefer explicit safeguard against duplicates, though it can be skipped at least in modern versions
  .map(s => (s, s.length())) // or .map(s => s -> s.length())
  .toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
val names: List[String] = List("abc", "abcd", "abcde")
val out_map: Map[String, Int] = Map(names.map(x => x -> x.length()): _*)
```

It uses the Map factory method with the key-value pairs as arguments.